# JavaScript Regex to Match Phone numbers but not in HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

We're needing a match phone numbers in some chunks of HTML with JavaScript and are very close but are having problems. We don't want to match phone numbers that show up in attributes such as `max-length="404-555-1212"`. Consider the following text:

```
Sample:

Shouldn’t Match:
max-length='0123456789'
max-length="0123456789"
max-length=012-345-6789"

Don’t want the >
<strong>866.643.4170</strong>

Don’t really want this plus included either:
+1-(800)-555-2468

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 +-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567     +1-(800)-555-2468
```

With the following Regex, we are able to grab all of the phone numbers but it does not exclude the attributes:

```
/(\d{1}[-. ])?\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]? *\d{3}-? *[-. ]?\d{4}/g
```

We tried the following but it is leaving the `>` at the end of `<strong>`:

```
/[^"='](\d{1}[-. ])?\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]? *\d{3}-? *[-. ]?\d{4}/g
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: Are the unwanted attributes always called "max-length", or can they be anything? Is there ever an equals sign before a phone number?

Comment: Do not run regexp's against HTML. Instead, extract the values and run regexps against them.

Comment: @Schlaus The attribute can be anything, not just max-length. There would never be an = before the legitimate phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So someone answered this question yesterday and I was coming back to accept the answer but it had been removed. However, the solution that they provided did work so, for posterity, I wanted to post the solution that they had given.

Here is the regex that solves the problem:

```
/(?:\d[-. ])?\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}(?!["'])/g
```

And here is a link to the working example:

http://regex101.com/r/rK6wY1/1

I wish I could have given credit to the original answerer.